# Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(\omega x) \exp(-x^{\alpha}) \, {\rm d} x \ge {\alpha^2 \sqrt{\pi} \over 8} \exp \left( -\frac{\omega^2}{4} \right)$

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, inequalities, fourier-analysis, special-functions

I would like  to prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(\omega x) \exp(-x^{\alpha}) \, {\rm d} x \ge 
{\alpha^2 \sqrt{\pi} \over 8} \exp \left( -\frac{\omega^2}{4} \right)$$

for any $\omega > 0$ and $1 < \alpha < 2$.

Here is some research effort. By using the representation of the generalized Gaussian density ($c_\alpha\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})$, $c_{\alpha}>0$ normalizing constant) as Gaussian mixture, I can prove that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(\omega x) \exp(-x^{\alpha}) \, {\rm d} x \ge 
{\Gamma(1/\alpha) \over \alpha} \exp \left( -\frac{\omega^2}{2}
{\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over \Gamma(1/\alpha)} \right).$$

When $\alpha=2$, ${\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over 2 \Gamma(1/\alpha)}={1\over 4}$ and $ {\Gamma(1/\alpha) \over \alpha}= {\alpha^2 \sqrt{\pi} \over 8} $ and $\mbox{Var}(\xi)= {\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over\Gamma(1/\alpha)}$ when $ \xi \sim c_\alpha\exp(-|x|^{\alpha})$.

Both ${\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over 2 \Gamma(1/\alpha)}$ and $ {\Gamma(1/\alpha) \over \alpha}$ are decreasing in $\alpha \in (1,2)$.  I need the result as originally stated as the coefficient in front of $\omega$ in the exponent has to be free from $\alpha$. All of my attempts are tied to probablisitic arguments and hence I fail to get rid of ${\Gamma(3/\alpha)\over 2 \Gamma(1/\alpha)}$ coefficient.

---

Related question

- [How to prove that $ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { \Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}\over \Gamma(1/2+m)} { (-t^2/4)^{m}\over m !} \ge (\alpha/2)^{3}\exp(-t^{2}/4) $](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366484/how-to-prove-that-sum-m-0-infty-gamma-12m-alpha-over-gamma1)

Comment: It is false for $\omega=0$, $\alpha=2$.

Comment: I presume your $dc$ should be $dx$; the inequality is badly violated; say for $\omega=1$ the l.h.s. and r.h.s. cross at $\alpha=1.4$.

Comment: this inequality does hold ($\omega>0$, $1<\alpha<2$): $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(\omega x)\exp(-x^{\alpha})dx \ge 
{\alpha^2 \sqrt{\pi} \over 8} \exp(-\omega^2/4) .$$ Equality is reached at $\alpha=2$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, yes, thank you, it should be $\sqrt{\pi}$- I have edited the question

Comment: More precise bounds are known; see e.g. Chen, Z-Q., Kim, P. and Song, R., [Heat kernel estimates for the
Dirichlet fractional Laplacian](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=1435-9855&vol=12&iss=5&rank=9), 2010.

Comment: @user90189, thank you so much for the reference, all the bounds are are given without specific constants, here, I need that specific constant . I know as $i\to\infty$ $f(\omega) \sim \omega^{(-\alpha-1)}$, the next step is to get the constants for that tail.

Comment: Maybe this is helping for the large $\omega$ expansion: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4796.pdf

Comment: ... in the paper arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4796.pdf that I recommended above, the asymptotics for your integral is $Q_{\beta}$, Eq. (13), The author's $\beta$ is your $\alpha$.

Comment: @JohannesTrost, thank you for the reference.  I do not see how to use it though. It has a different representation, yes, very useful for asymptotics.  I still do not see how I can get my lower bound. The truncation error cam provide some upper bound only. What am I missing?

Comment: @TanyaVladi I was referring to your answer to user90189's comment.The constants for the tail $\sim \omega^{-\alpha-1}$ are given in the paper.

Comment: @JohannesTrost, I understand, thank you for the clarification, however I am not interested in the tail, I need inequality to hold,  you can  think about it  as for medium $\omega$, neither small nor large