# How to prove that $ \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} { \Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}\over \Gamma(1/2+m)} { (-t^2/4)^{m}\over m !} \ge (\alpha/2)^{3}\exp(-t^{2}/4) $

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, special-functions

I would love to prove the following inequality
$$
 {1\over \sqrt{\pi} } \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}
{ (-t^2)^{m}\over (2m) !}=$$
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
{ \Gamma\{(1+2m)/\alpha\}\over \Gamma(1/2+m)}
{ (-t^2/4)^{m}\over m !} \ge (\alpha/2)^{3}\exp(-t^{2}/4)
$$
$1<\alpha<2$, $t>0$,
The question is connected to the other question I asked and got no answer for [Prove $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(\omega x) \exp(-x^{\alpha}) \, {\rm d} x \ge {\alpha^2 \sqrt{\pi} \over 8} \exp \left( -\frac{\omega^2}{4} \right)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366302/prove-int-0-infty-cos-omega-x-exp-x-alpha-rm-d-x-ge-alp)

Comment: @AlapanDas, awesome, thank you

Comment: @AlapanDas, also the series is alternating sign, is the first step of the proof well justified ?